# Check if a specific UIViewController is in TabBarItems

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Using UITabBarController I'm trying to programmatically add or delete certain ViewControllers as tabs if the user is logged in or not.

I add the ViewController 'SecondViewController' by using this code:

```
[newTabs addObject:second];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newTabs];
```

And, I run the code below to check if that particular ViewController (second) is in the array. But it doesn't work: vs is never equal to second.

```
NSMutableArray *newTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
BOOL found = FALSE;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *second = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
for (UIViewController *vc in newTabs){
    if([vc isEqual: second]){
        found=TRUE;
    }
}
```

When I do a NSLog, this is the response:

```
2014-02-01 18:38:18.755 App Login Test[1469:11303] PostData: <SecondViewController: 0x71a2830>
2014-02-01 18:38:18.756 App Login Test[1469:11303] PostData: <SecondViewController: 0x75bcd90>
```

(This is when I run a NSLog of vc and of second, to compare both, and understand why they aren't equal.)

I've been looking for a while but I can't find an explanation for this! found should be set to TRUE, but it never happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `UIViewController isEqual:` simply checks the memory address. Therefore, two separate instances will not be equal.

One solution would be to check the object's type.

```
for (UIViewController *vc in newTabs){
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]){
        found=TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
will generate a new instance of the SecondViewController.

Also confirmed as per Apple docs 
"This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it."

Therefore your comparison of isEqual is not necessarily going to work. Instead you could do something like this:
...
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[second class]]) {
....

A possibly better way to do what you are trying to achieve is store the reference to SecondViewController instead of instantiating a new SecondViewController every time. Then you could use isEqual: to check if the view controller is already in the UITabBarController and add the instance you already have if it does not exist.